# Secure place to store encryption/decryption key on android

Tags: android, encryption

In my scenario, the app user should not be able to manipulate a set of strings, because they are incomplete game scores that goes to a leader-board when they complete the game. If they modify them it is a unnecessary advantage. 
I tested string encryption and storing in a file using the code shown here.
https://github.com/tozny/java-aes-crypto/blob/master/AesCbcWithIntegrityTests.java

It says

> *Note: If you are generating a random key, you'll probably be storing it somewhere*

Whats the best place to store this key or is there a better way to achieve my objective.

```
 try {
        SecretKeys key;

        key = generateKey();
       //Note: If you are generating a random key, you'll probably be storing it somewhere


        // The encryption / storage & display:

        String keyStr = keyString(key);
        key = null; //Pretend to throw that away so we can demonstrate converting it from str
        String path = getPath();
        String textToEncrypt = savePuzzle(path + "/intput.txt");
        Log.i("Tozny", "Before encryption: " + textToEncrypt);

        // Read from storage & decrypt
        key = keys(keyStr); // alternately, regenerate the key from password/salt.
        CipherTextIvMac civ = encrypt(textToEncrypt, key);
        String temp = civ.toString();
        Log.i("Tozny", "Encrypted: " + temp);


        CipherTextIvMac civ2 = new CipherTextIvMac(temp);
        String decryptedText = decryptString(civ2, key);
```

Comment: I'd just like to note that on rooted phones, you can easily access the `SharedPreferences` that are just a plain-text XML document. So don't even think about that.

Comment: What about storing it on your server? Only limitation is user must have internet connection when score is saved

Comment: What you are really searching for is a professional app protection and obfuscation framework (something like Apk protect, DexGuard, DashO, DexProtector or Stringer).

Comment: Thanks all for your input. I think server or obfuscation are the only option.

Answer (score 1):

Use the AndroidKeyStore adding a keystoreEntry.

This link can help you: 
http://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html

Answer (score -1):

there are lots of ways.

-provide in resources (can be easily decompiled)

- stoing as constant (cam be decompiled)
- what i prefer
  create class called MyKeyGenerator.
  make some logic like appending,reverse,or etc operations and finally we get some key.
  use code Obfuskation  using progauard.

might this usefull to you.

Comment: Thanks, so the logic on MyKeyGenerator would be hiding the limitation of progauard, because it wont hide the keys right?  Do you have any good tried out MyKeyGenerator logic?